# Is there a GUI tool that can provide the functionality of the Windows Device Manager?

Tags: devices

There's some thing's I'd like to do with the devices on my system, such as stopping, starting and rebooting and I was wondering if there's a tool, either in Ubuntu or the software centre, that can replicate the functionality of the Windows Device Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no graphical tool to do those things that I can find. Although some of the things like stopping are hard to do even from the command line since the kernel really isn't friendly to being poked by userspace about what should be turned on.

If you want it could be a project to get involved with:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment

Answer (score 2):

Check out indicator-usb. It's a small indicator displayed when devices are plugged. With it, you can unmount them easily.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/safely-remove-usb-drives-using-a-nifty-application-indicator-updated-with-new-icon/